# PHP Moip class autoloader

Tags: php, php-autoload

Como faço para fazer esse require 'vendor/autoload.php', ele não vem na documentação.

```
 <?php
 require 'vendor/autoload.php';

 use Moip\Moip;
 use Moip\MoipBasicAuth;

 $endpoint = 'test.moip.com.br';
 $token = '01010101010101010101010101010101';
 $key = 'ABABABABABABABABABABABABABABABABABABABAB';

 $moip = new Moip(new MoipBasicAuth($token, $key), $endpoint);

 $customer = $moip->customers()->setOwnId('sandbox_v2_1401147277')
                          ->setFullname('Jose Silva')
                          ->setEmail('sandbox_v2_1401147277@email.com')
                          ->setBirthDate('1988-12-30')
                          ->setTaxDocument('33333333333')
                          ->setPhone(11, 66778899)
                          ->addAddress('BILLING',
                                       'Avenida Faria Lima', 2927,
                                       'Itaim', 'Sao Paulo', 'SP',
                                       '01234000', 8);

 print_r($order = $moip->orders()->setOwnId('sandbox_v2_1401147277')
                    ->addItem('Pedido de testes Sandbox - 1401147277', 1, 'Mais info...', 10000)
                    ->setShippingAmount(100)
                    ->setCustomer($customer)
                    ->create());
```

Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

O novo SDK do Moip usa o **Composer** sendo assim basta que você instale as dependências do projeto e o autoload fará todo trabalho para você.

Você deve instalar o composer em seu projeto, [veja aqui (conteúdo em Inglês)](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md).

Depois do composer instalado e com o projeto clonado em maquina, execute o comando

```
composer install
```

Depois que as dependências tenham sido instaladas você pode executar o **sample.php** normalmente em seu browser.

A documentação do **novo SDK** PHP Moip também está atualizada, acho que poderá ajudar.

SDK Moip v2(php): https://github.com/moip/moip-sdk-php